# Building a SlideShow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I need to include a slideshow in my app, a simple one. One images fades in while the other fades out in its place and so on. The slide show will reside in a custom view.

Should I do it by hand — I mean, create many views with images and call their animators so change the opacity — or am I missing something in the documentation?

I wonder if there is a "built-in" way. If not, what are the usual steps to do it? Maybe what I have in my head is not the proper manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need 2, or 3 views, and dynamically change their content.
2 views you could cross fade by making the top view transparent, then changing it's content, then making it opaque changing the back views content, making the front view transparent again...if you wanted to fade to black or white you could have a middle view that you fade to.

Comment: Thanks Grady Player, very clever.